# Simple Grouped Barplot (ggplot)

Tags: bar-chart

I want to do a barplot like this one (with different values):

[image: barplot]

Here's my dataframe:

[image: dataframe]

Here's the top part of my code:

```
library("openxlsx")
library(ggplot2)
library("reshape")

df1<- read.xlsx("graficosparaR.xlsx", sheet = 'Hoja2', colNames = TRUE)
```

I tried using `ggplotfunction`, but I can't get it (I'm a beginner R user).

Could you help me writing the code for the barplot?